# code for the power of the equation

Tags: equation-solving

If I have the equation with n terms

```
M = Sum [x^(a_i) y^(b_i) z^(c_i]     i=1,2,...,n`
```

I need a code to find the points:

```
   pts = {{a_1,b_1,c_1}, {a_2,b_2,c_2},....,{a_n,b_n,c_n}}
```

For example 1:

```
M = x^4 + x^2 z^4 + y z^6 + z^10 + y^4
```

Here n = 5  and the answer will be:

```
pts = {{4, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 4}, {0, 1, 6}, {0, 0, 10}, {0, 4, 0}}
```

another example 2:

```
M= x^2 y^3 z + x y^2 z^5 + x^2 y^3 z^2
```

Here n = 3 and pts will be:

```
pts = {{2, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 5}, {2, 3, 2}}
```

I want to add also,
If I have the point `{a_i,b_i,c_i}` I will have `A_i = a_i + b_i*u + c_i*v`

so since I have 3 points in example 2:
the answer will be:

```
A1=2+3u+v
A2=1+2u+5v
A3=2+3u+2v
```

Thank you

Comment: `CoefficientRules`, e.g.: `CoefficientRules[x^4 + x^2 z^4 + y z^6 + z^10 + y^4][[All, 1]]`

Comment: @ubpdqn  Thank you I add another part.

Comment: I don't understand the last example you added.

Comment: for example if I got the point {1,2,3} I need code to give me equation for this point such that A1=1+2u+3v this equation contains 3 parts 1, 2u, and 3v and it is from the point {1,2,3} the first part of the point does not change the 2nd add u , the 3rd add v ,,,,,,, another example if I have the point {1,5,2} the 1st will not change it is (1), the 2nd here is 5 so it will be 5u, and the 3rd here is 2 so the 3rd part will be 2v ,,,, and my equation will be A2= 1+ 5u +2v

Comment: @AteqAlsaadi just do `result.{1,u,v}`

Comment: the result must be:
'A1=2+3u+v
A2=1+2u+5v
A3=2+3u+2v'

Answer (score 2):

Putting ubpdqn's comments into an answer.
if this is not what you want please add further clarification.

```
m = x^2 y^3 z + x y^2 z^5 + x^2 y^3 z^2;

result = CoefficientRules[m][[All, 1]]

result.{1, u, v}

{a3, a1, a2} = %;

a1
a2
a3
```

> ```
> {{2, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 5}}
>
> {2 + 3 u + 2 v, 2 + 3 u + v, 1 + 2 u + 5 v}
>
> 2 + 3 u + v
>
> 1 + 2 u + 5 v
>
> 2 + 3 u + 2 v
> ```